# Redirect from domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Tags: htaccess, redirect

Lets say my site domain is **main.com** and this is a wordpress site.
I have 4 subdomains,say, cat1,cat2,ca3,cat4.
Random posts and pages are displayed on main.com.They come into either of 4 categories ie cat1,cat2,ca3,cat4.
Now whenever I click on any page under category cat1 its URL should be displayed as **cat1.main.com/pagename**.
Similarly this should happen for other pages in every category.
Does this require any redirection or something else?
How can I achieve this?Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have separate Wordpress sites set up in each of your subdomains? If so, I can't understand why you would want to structure your site like this, because your databases won't communicate with each other. For example if you create a post in domain.com, you'll have to recreate it in subdomain.domain.com. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: No I dont have seperate sites.All I want is whenever I click on any page,its category should be set as name for subdomain.